# How to set up offline manifest for a web app to run in Safari in iOS?

Tags: web-applications, safari, ios

I'm currently trying to set up an offline.manifest file for my web app to be used offline on an iOS device. For testing purposes I have a very simple HTML page that I'm trying to add to a home screen. I'm testing it on a live iPhone 4, but after the page is added to the home screen and I put the iPhone in the airplane mode and try to start my web app I get this error:

> "Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data"

and then if I click OK I get:

> "Cannot Open Web App Name" "Web App Name could not be opened because
>   it is not connected to the Internet"

The following is added to the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" manifest="scrts/offline.manifest">
```

and the offline.manifest is composed as such:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

../pics/bkgnd_iphn_settings.png
../pics/mbl_btn_fb.png
../pics/mbl_btn_twt.png
../pics/icon_57_57_bg.png
../pics/icon_72_72_bg.png
../pics/icon_114_114_bg.png
../pics/icon_144_144_bg.png
../pics/splash_320_460_bg.png
../pics/splash_768_1004_bg.png
../pics/splash_1004_768_bg.png
```

I got all instructions on composing it from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html)

I also adjusted the .htaccess file to add this line:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
```

Any idea what am I not doing right?

Comment: Is that your whole cache manifest file? You only cache images, not the html file or other things like css and so on. Do you have that in there?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It says in that link I provided, "You do not need to include the URL of the HTML file in which the manifest is declared." Do I still need it anyway?

Comment: I used [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

Comment: Thanks. Their manifest includes index.html. I was wondering, if my pages are generated via a php script, what do I put there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) is pretty good and if your pages are generated dynamically, you may use a .htaccess to rewrite `domain.com/script.html` to `domain.com/script.php` and then call the `*.html` from your app. This way the content on the device is saved as html and could be delivered statically. You can also add fallback urls/files to your manifest file which may be useful if your content is dynamically by default.

Comment: Michael, it's a little bit more complex than that. Each of the pages is referenced implicitly using an index.php page. For instance if a user directs their browser to domain.com/info indeed the server loads up domain.com/info/index.php. And I cannot mess with the html/php associations either due to the server/php structure of the site. So how shall I specify those pages in the manifest file without changing .htaccess?

Comment: I don't understand that part: `I cannot mess with the html/php associations either due to the server/php structure of the site`. You just have to add a little bit of code to the `.htaccess`, so no need to alter the application itself. I don't know another possibility for making a site available offline than the manifest. Have you tried to directly use the `*.php`-files? Maybe the device also saves the headers, then it should be simply used as `text/html` and everything is fine.